# Calculate actions per hour / day from time application has been running for

Tags: java

How would I use the current application running time in milliseconds to calculate the number of actions that can be performed per hour / day?

Here's the current code I have:

```
int secs = (int) (Settings.totalTime / 1000) % 60 ;
int mins = (int) ((Settings.totalTime / (1000*60)) % 60);
int hrs   = (int) ((Settings.totalTime / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
timerunning.setText("<html><body style='width:200px;'><center><br>" + hrs + " hrs, "+ mins +" mins, " + secs + " secs<br><br></body></html>");
long hour = Settings.actions == 0 ? 0 : ((60 *(Settings.totalTime / 60000)) / Settings.actions);
long day = Settings.actions == 0 ? 0 : ((24 * 60 *(Settings.totalTime / 60000)) / Settings.actions);
```

Settings.totaltime is the current time in milliseconds that the application has been running for.

And here's what's returned after 3 actions and 15 mins running time:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/65ZtC.png